# CNN Keras - unexpected prediction result

Tags: python, keras, prediction, conv-neural-network

Im trying to create a keras CNN to predict my ECG data. My x_train is shaped like 640,3498,1, y_train like 640,2 (with to_categorical 2 classes) and I'm trying to build model.

X_train:

```
  [[[ 3.96889100e-12]
  [ 2.96721687e-12]
  [ 3.76118701e-12]
  ...
  [ 4.50912277e-12]
  [ 4.10963106e-12]
  [ 4.28550483e-12]]

 [[-3.28395026e-12]
  [-1.30043687e-12]
  [ 1.66892740e-12]
  ...
  [ 0.00000000e+00]
  [ 0.00000000e+00]
  [ 0.00000000e+00]]

 [[-3.71662156e-11]
  [-3.47206950e-11]
  [-3.72873674e-11]
  ...
  [-3.59975902e-11]
  [-3.60138075e-11]
  [-3.74937527e-11]]
```

y_train:

```
[[1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]]
```

The code I'm using is this:

```
ctivation = 'relu'
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01),
                 kernel_initializer='normal', activation=activation, input_shape=X_train_dfm.shape[1:]))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)) 

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01),
                 kernel_initializer='normal', activation=activation))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)) 

model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01),
                 kernel_initializer='normal', activation=activation))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)) 

model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01),
                 kernel_initializer='normal', activation=activation))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer = adam, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

The expected values are integers 0-1 . However, the predictions are floats between ~-0.4 and 0.5 all of that.

i've tried with 10 testing data. Thats what i got

```
[[0.4986445  0.50135547]
 [0.4986445  0.50135547]
 [0.4986445  0.50135547]
 [0.4986445  0.50135547]
 [0.4986445  0.50135547]
 [0.4986445  0.50135547]
 [0.4986445  0.50135547]
 [0.4986445  0.50135547]
 [0.4986445  0.50135547]
 [0.4986445  0.50135547]]

val_loss, val_accuracy : [0.6938661336898804, 0.5062500238418579]
```

Please help me, i got stuck in a week. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see a call to `model.fit(...)`. Have you called that? How many epochs are you training for? There's a `verbose` option to `fit` that can show additional information that may be helpful for debugging. Are you using that option?

Comment: You have softmax, so those float numbers are the probabilities of the prediction belonging to class one or two. Add an additional dense layer of size 128-256 before the softmax layer. Since you have two classes, you should change your implementation to 'binary_crossentropy' by changing the softmax to sigmoid and reshaping your y_train to (640,1) where each row value is 0 if the sample belongs to class one and 1 if the sample belongs to class two.

Comment: ive tried what u suggest @NimaAghli, add dense change loss to 'binary_crossentrophy' and change to sigmoid then reshape y_train. 
output prediction 10 data `[[0.48019227]
 [0.48019227]
 [0.48019227]
 [0.48019227]
 [0.48019227]
 [0.48019227]
 [0.48019227]
 [0.48019227]
 [0.4801923 ]
 [0.4801923 ]]`

Comment: here is my model.fit @dannyadam
`model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5, verbose=1, validation_data(X_test, y_test))`

Comment: 5 epochs is very low. Try 50 and also lower your learning rate to 0.001. If possible, share the verbose output of training.

Comment: Not expert in ECG data but isn't it time series data? Might be a better idea to use LSTM.

Comment: thankyou for your help @NimaAghli, but i still got some output predictions by increasing epochs and change lr. idk why this is happen, whether the data I use is wrong

Comment: I think in your question you are not actually saying what you think is wrong, so what is wrong or unexpected here?